# Why is my plot shrinking after I tried to set the x-axis range?

Tags: python, seaborn

[image]

---

Why are the plots shrinking all to the left when I try to set the x-axis range? The largest value of my x is actually 70, but I want to make my plot to go to `x=90` (so from `x=70` to `x=90`, it should be blank).

```
# plotting
xmin = 0
xmax = 90
ymin = 0
ymax = 100

plt.figure(linewidth = 2.5)
plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.pointplot(data = df, 
               x = "Time",
               y = "Percent", 
               hue = "Concentration", 
               errorbar = "se", 
               scale = 0.7, 
               errwidth=1)

plt.xlabel("Time", fontsize = '12')
plt.ylabel("Percent Activity", fontsize = '12')
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
# xticks = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
# ax.set_xticks(xticks, labels=xticks)

ax.legend(title = 'Concentration(uM)', 
      loc = 'lower left', 
      title_fontsize='7',
      fontsize ='7')

plt.show()
```

I tried setting the xticks, but it doesn't work. The graphs are still shrinking.

The data:

[image]

As recommended, I tried `df.describe()` for `df`. And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of data you are using, especially the type and value of your x axe "Time"? Plotting with time-series data can always be tricky.

Comment: Note that your code is very confusing. The two calls to `plt.figure` and the call to `plt.subplots` each create their own (initially empty) figure.  You should replace these 3 calls by just one, combining the parameters you want to change: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=..., linewidth=...)`

Comment: @JohnHany. Hi, sorry please check for my data.  I am graphing Time VS Percent here for each Genotype. And if there are multiple trials for one Genotype, then the values should be averaged. 

Time,Genotype,Trial,Percent
0,tgMOR,1,100
10,tgMOR,1,100
20,tgMOR,1,90
30,tgMOR,1,70
40,tgMOR,1,60
50,tgMOR,1,50
60,tgMOR,1,30
70,tgMOR,1,80
80,tgMOR,1,80
0,tgMOR;rsbp-1,1,100
10,tgMOR;rsbp-1,1,90.90909091
20,tgMOR;rsbp-1,1,100
30,tgMOR;rsbp-1,1,81.81818182
40,tgMOR;rsbp-1,1,63.63636364

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the support. I used df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(float), but it doesn't work. The same problem persists.

Comment: @JohanC The plot still shrinks like how it was before after I used df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(float). Also, yes, I am reading data via pd.read_csv(). Results of df.describe() is shown above.

Comment: You are supposed to add these data as text, never as image. Anyway, the problem is that `sns.pointplot` by default uses a "categorical x-axis" (internally at positions 0,1,2,3,....). The latest seaborn version has an option `sns.pointplot(..., native_scale=True)` which will put the values on their numerical position. Alternatively, you could replace `sns.pointplot` with `sns.lineplot` which always works numerically.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to set the range of x-axis for a seaborn pointplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643897/how-to-set-the-range-of-x-axis-for-a-seaborn-pointplot)

Answer (score 1):

```py
ax = sns.pointplot(data=df, 
                   x="Time",
                   y="Percent", 
                   hue="Concentration", 
                   errorbar="see", 
                   scale=0.7,
                   errwidth=1,
                   native_scale=True    # <---------                 
                   )
```

sns.pointplot converts the x-axis to a consecutive integer list. Your x-input of 0, 10, ..., 100 changes to 0, 1, ..., 10 with each integer being a sample. Enabling "native_scale" should revert this as per https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html .

> native_scale (bool)
>
> When True, numeric or datetime values on the categorical axis will
> maintain their original scaling rather than being converted to fixed
> indices.

Note: By default, the scale will change depending on how many samples you have and is irrespective of the actual x-values. In other words, without native_scale, the output x-values are dependent on the number of samples, not the input x-values.

This question is related on the issues of changing axis with seaborn plots and may provide guidance, though it's not a duplicate; [How to set the range of x-axis for a seaborn pointplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643897/how-to-set-the-range-of-x-axis-for-a-seaborn-pointplot)

Comment: Did you just invent the functionality of the `scale=` parameter? It doesn't rescale the x-axis, it scales the size of the circular markers. By the way, [How to set the range of x-axis for a seaborn pointplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643897/how-to-set-the-range-of-x-axis-for-a-seaborn-pointplot) is an excellent original for this duplicate question.

Comment: @JohanC Well darn, sorry the main premise of the answer was wrong; happy to be of some help though! Perhaps setting "native_scale=True" will help as per https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have a new error that shows "pointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'native_scale'". I guess it's cause my seaborn is an older version, so I couldn't use this method before. Thank you so much though!